# How to correctly copy elements and render them again?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a copy of all elements and re-render them.

The following code doesn't make sense to do this, but I need it to manage and modify the placement of individual children.

The code returns nothing, although the items in the collection are.

My code I'm trying to execute:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const renderElment = (child) => {
  return <div ref={(ref) => ref.appendChild(child)}></div>;
};

export default function CopyPage() {
  const ref = React.createRef();
  const [components, setComponents] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const children = [];
      for (const child of ref.current.children) {
        const clone = React.cloneElement(child, {}, null);
        children.push(clone);
      }
      setComponents(children);
    }
  }, [ref]);

  if (components.length > 0) {
    components.map((child) => {
      return renderElment(child);
    });
  } else {
    return (
      <div ref={ref}>
        <div title={"Title 1"}>
          <p>XDZ</p>
        </div>
        <div title={"Title 2"}>
          <p>XDZ</p>
          <p>XDZ</p>
        </div>
        <div title={"Title 3"}>
          <p>XDZ</p>
          <p>XDZ</p>
          <p>XDZ</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-ellis-hflv2t?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Why would you like to do this?

Comment: @Konrad I am previewing this file as pdf in html. When I have elements in the collection, I will control which page a specific component should be on. I will check in the loop how many elements can fit on one A4 page and only add so much. Existing libraries do not meet the requirements. I have a lot of different headers and footers on different pages and some dynamic content.

Comment: You don't copy elements. You just generate the components you need, where you need them, and you let React take care of how it does that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the copying of elements. I have yet to test with more advanced elements like Canvas.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function CopyPage() {
    const ref = React.createRef();
    const [components, setComponents] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current !== null) {
            if (ref?.current?.children) {
                const elements = [];
                for (const child of ref?.current?.children) {
                    const elm = React.createElement(child.tagName, {
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: child.outerHTML }
                    });
                    elements.push(elm);
                }

                if (components.length === 0) {
                    setComponents(elements);
                }
            }
        }
    }, [ref]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div ref={ref}>
                <div title={"Title 1"}>
                    <p>XDZ</p>
                </div>
                <div title={"Title 2"}>
                    <p>XDZ</p>
                    <p>XDZ</p>
                </div>
                <div title={"Title 3"}>
                    <p>XDZ</p>
                    <p>XDZ</p>
                    <p>XDZ</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style={{ background: "green" }}>
                {components?.map((c) => {
                    console.log(c);
                    return <div>{c}</div>;
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-dewdney-pn299v?file=/src/App.js)

[CodeSandBox - version with deletion of previous data](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-lalande-2keyoy?file=/src/App.js)

If there is a better solution, it would be useful to add it.

Comment: This is an extremely bad non-React solution to a problem that isn't a problem: just generate your components twice, React is stupidly efficient at this, and if you write your code with proper keys, it can perform virtual DOM diffing in subsequent renders just fine.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans To know the height of a component I have to render it. And what I do with it and where I put it depends on their height. Is there any other way than to render twice?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans First I need to know what it looks like to determine where it should be. I need all the data like the height of the element, position relative to the top of the page, etc. This is not a typical situation

Comment: Those sound like details that [should be in your post](/help/how-to-ask), not in comments.